# SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character in React Application

Tags: reactjs

I'm following [this](https://github.com/WebDevSimplified/Whatsapp-Clone) tutorial, and when i change something and refresh browser, out of no where this error pops up,

`SyntaxError: JSON.parse: unexpected character at line 1 column 1 of the JSON data`

Here's the complete script giving error message,

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react'

const PREFIX = 'whatsapp-clone-'

export default function useLocalStorage(key, initialValue) {
  const prefixedKey = PREFIX + key
  const [value, setValue] = useState(() => {

    const jsonValue = localStorage.getItem(prefixedKey);

    if (jsonValue != null) {
        return JSON.parse(jsonValue);
    }

    if (typeof initialValue === 'function') {
      console.log(jsonValue)
      return initialValue()
    } else {
      console.log(jsonValue)

      return initialValue
    }
  })

  useEffect(() => {
    localStorage.setItem(prefixedKey, JSON.stringify(value))
  }, [prefixedKey, value])

  return [value, setValue]
}
```

[image]

And these are the other places where error pops

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Does it have anything to do with webpack configurations ?

If that line commented then it works,

Any idea why this happens

Comment: I believe that error might be happening due to potentially malformed JSON. What is the value of jsonValue if you console log it?

Comment: @adrian , initially it's undefined.

Comment: And if you console log it from within the if statement- what value do you get?

Comment: `undefined` is what i get

Comment: check your comparison : if (jsonValue != null), for json.Parse work you must pass a valid json string.

Answer (score -1):

Just **restart** the **code editor** or **IDE** and run the app again to see the expected changes.

Comment: The problem here seems more related to parsing a JSON stream rather than a problem with the IDE.